# DataTestMethod - Get dynamic data from both TestInitialize and TestCleanup methods

Tags: c#, mstest

I have a DynamicData test which is based on:
https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-data-tests.htm#using-dynamicdata

In my own case, I have a Pre Test (TestInitialize) and Post-Test (TestCleanup), and I need to get the dynamic data value from that pre-test and post-test. I mean, I need to get the the value of the arguments "a", "b" and "expected" from  both TestInitialize and TestCleanup methods.

Here is a sample code:

```html
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void Test_Add_DynamicData_Method(int a, int b, int expected)
{
    var actual = MathHelper.Add(a, b);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetData()
{
    yield return new object[] { 1, 1, 2 };
    yield return new object[] { 12, 30, 42 };
    yield return new object[] { 14, 1, 15 };
}

[TestInitialize]
public virtual void PreTest()
{
           
}

[TestCleanup]
public virtual void PostTest()
{
            
}
```

Can you please assist?

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the post. Hope it is clear now